# Go Modules: finding out right pseudo-version (vX.Y.Z-<timestamp>-<commit>) of required package

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying out Go modules. My project requires the libarary `golang.org/x/net/html`, so I defined this `go.mod` file:

```
module github.com/patrickbucher/prettyprint

require golang.org/x/net/html
```

And wrote this demo program to check if the dependency gets loaded upon compilation:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"

        "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
        doc, err := html.Parse(os.Stdin)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

When I run go build, I get this error message:

```
go: errors parsing go.mod:
~/prettyprint/go.mod:3: usage: require module/path v1.2.3
```

Obviously, I missed the version number. But which one to take? I stumbled an article called [Takig Go Modules for a Spin](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/07/14/taking-go-modules-for-a-spin), where I found an example of a `go.mod` file containing references to `golang.org/x` packages:

```
module github.com/davecheney/httpstat

require (
        github.com/fatih/color v1.5.0
        github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.0.9
        github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.3
        golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20170922011244-0744d001aa84
        golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20170922123423-429f518978ab
        golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915090833-1cbadb444a80
)
```

The author is using version strings like `v0.0.0-20170922011244-0744d001aa84`, consisting of the semver indication v0.0.0, a timestamp and something that looks like a git commit ID.

How do I figure out those version strings? I guess those `golang.org/x` packages will be versioned according to semantic versioning at some point, but to really trying out `go mod`, I need to figure out those *now*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A version of the form `v0.0.0-20180906233101-161cd47e91fd` means that there are no tagged versions on the git repository. So `go mod` generates one based on the latest commit time and the prefix of the commit hash.

To get a correct `go.mod` file start out using the following command (assuming go 1.11):

```
go mod init yourmodulename
```

Or create an empty go.mod file that just contains the following:

```
module yourmodulename
```

then run `go mod tidy`, this will find all dependencies, add the missing and remove the unused dependencies.

Comment: Minor side note: you don't necessarily need to run `go mod tidy` to have the `go` command automatically determine the corresponding pseudo-version in this case. Other commands like `go build`, `go test`, etc. would also have recorded the version.  Some more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315225/11210494).  `go mod tidy` has its [uses](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#why-does-go-mod-tidy-record-indirect-and-test-dependencies-in-my-gomod), but sometimes people think they need to run it more often than strictly needed. In any event, still valid to do so.

Answer (score 35):

**Update**

This command is the better solution to adding the `replace` command to `go.mod` rather than doing it manually using `git` that I initially posted:

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/docker/docker=github.com/docker/engine@ea84732a7725
```

produces a similar result but instead of using a pseudo-version, it finds the tagged engine version.

```
replace github.com/docker/docker => github.com/docker/engine v17.12.0-ce-rc1.0.20191113042239-ea84732a7725+incompatible
```

Alternatively, include a tagged docker version.

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/docker/docker@v1.13.1=github.com/docker/engine@ea84732a7725
```

for

```
replace github.com/docker/docker v1.13.1 => github.com/docker/engine v17.12.0-ce-rc1.0.20191113042239-ea84732a7725+incompatible
```

Thanks to [@Shivam010 on Medium](https://medium.com/@Shivam010/well-if-you-want-to-replace-your-package-to-any-other-tag-commit-try-this-5302b0b76b71)

---

**Original, deprecated answer**

Here's how I did it.

Checkout the repository on the desired branch/tag. e.g.

```
git clone -b v19.03.5 git@github.com:docker/engine.git
```

Then

```
cd engine
TZ=UTC git --no-pager show \
  --quiet \
  --abbrev=12 \
  --date='format-local:%Y%m%d%H%M%S' \
  --format="%cd-%h"
```

And i get

```
20191113042239-ea84732a7725
```

For use in `go.mod` as

```
replace github.com/docker/docker v1.13.1 => github.com/docker/engine v0.0.0-20191113042239-ea84732a7725
```

Comment: FWIW, it is fairly dangerous to try to format this yourself, and you can get it subtly wrong in a way that bites you later. Much better to let the 'go' command do it for you, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315225/11210494

Comment: This is very useful! If you want to [Inject build-time variables with Golang](https://blog.alexellis.io/inject-build-time-vars-golang/) into a binary then this is as  good a way to figure it out as I've found!

Comment: @typical182 Can you please test `github.com/docker/engine@v19.03.5` with `go get`? I'd serious love to know how to use `go get` to create the psuedo version for that package. I recommend verifying that it works. Just running what you'd expect, `go get github.com/docker/docker/engine@v19.03.5`, does not work since `but does not contain package github.com/docker/docker/engine`. If any of the `go` commands I tried had worked before posting this, i would not have shared this, i absolutely would have preferred using `go`. If you have a solution using `go get`, please share!

Comment: Docker is a complex case.  It probably makes sense for you to open a new question? If you comment here with a link, I will try to answer there.

Comment: I got error "version "13a8e353d7eb394c554f2e07171d942828ce5099" invalid: must be of the form v1.2.3"

Answer (score 11):

> The author is using version strings like v0.0.0-20170922011244-0744d001aa84, consisting of the semver indication v0.0.0, a timestamp and something that looks like a git commit ID.
>
> How do I figure out those version strings?

You never need to manually figure out those complex version strings, which are called [pseudo-versions](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions).

#### Daily workflow

Your typical daily workflow can be:

- Add import statements to your `.go` code as needed.
- Standard commands like `go build`, `go test`, or `go mod tidy` will automatically add new dependencies as needed to satisfy imports (updating `go.mod` and downloading the new dependencies). By default, the `@latest` version of a new direct dependency will be used.
- When needed, more specific versions of dependencies can be chosen with commands such as:

  - `go get foo@v1.2.3`
  - `go get foo@e3702bed2`
  - `go get foo@latest`
  - `go get foo@branch`
  - or by editing `go.mod` directly.

Note that you did not need to come up with a pseudo-version on your own in any of those examples, even when requesting a specific commit (e.g., `@e3702bed2`), or the latest commit on a branch (e.g., `@master`).

#### When do I see pseudo-versions in my `go.mod`?

If you end up with a version that resolves to a valid [semver](https://semver.org) tag with a leading `v` such as `v1.2.3` or `v1.2.4-beta-1`, then that semver tag will be recorded in your `go.mod` file. If the version does not have a valid semver tag, then it will be instead recorded with as a [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions) in your `go.mod` file, such as `v0.0.0-20171006230638-a6e239ea1c69`, which includes a version section, a commit timestamp, and a commit hash.

In your particular case, `golang.org/x/net/html` does not have any semver tags, which means if you do `go get golang.org/x/net/html@latest`, or `go get golang.org/x/net/html@0744d001aa84`, or just do `go build` after first including `import "golang.org/x/net/html"` in your `.go` file, then golang.org/x/net/html will be recorded in your `go.mod` as a pseudo-version, but note that you did not need to figure out the complex string yourself (because the `go` command translates [modules queries](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_queries) such as `go get golang.org/x/net/html@0744d001aa84` into the corresponding pseudo-version when needed, and records the result in your `go.mod`).

#### Why was the pseudo-version format chosen?

The pseudo-version format helps provide a simple total ordering across all versions based on standard [semver](https://semver.org) ordering, which makes it easier to reason about what commit will be considered "later" than another commit, or whether an actual semver tag is considered "later" than a separate commit.

#### Controlling dependency versions

You can read more about all of the above in the ["How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies"](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies) section of the Go Modules wiki, which also contains additional links into the official documentation.

Comment: What if those pseudo versions are in replace directives, which is required in a project importing Kubernetes dependencies (I think)?

Comment: Note that as of [Go1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command) build commands such as `go build` and `go test` behave as if `-mod=readonly` was used and will no longer automatically update `go.mod` (as mentioned in your second bullet point of Daily Workflow). You can use `-mod=mod` to allow the command to modify `go.mod` as before. (The `GOFLAGS` environment variable can be used to set default flags to Go commands if desired).

Answer (score 5):

Now I read a bit further in the documentation (`go help modules`) and stumbled upon `go mod tidy`:

> The 'go mod tidy' command builds that view and then adds any missing
>   module requirements and removes unnecessary ones.

So when I leave away the requirement on `golang.org/x/net/html` and prune my `go.mod` file to this:

```
module github.com/patrickbucher/prettyprint
```

And then run `go mod tidy`, then the requirement with the version number is correctly figured out based on **the import path in my source code**, and thus `go.mod` becoming:

```
module github.com/patrickbucher/prettyprint

require golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20180906233101-161cd47e91fd
```

Now both `go list` and `go build` work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a specific commit which has not yet been tagged, you could do the following -

```
module github.com/patrickbucher/prettyprint

require golang.org/x/net 73496e0df0ba4284f460d1955ddf6bb096957c9f
```

then run `go mod tidy` and you will automatically see the pseudo-version in the  go.mod file, becoming

```
module github.com/patrickbucher/prettyprint

require golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20180906233101-161cd47e91fd
```

(I borrowed the code snippet from Patrick's response above)

Comment: The canonical way to add such a `require` line to `go.mod` is via `go get`, e.g. `go get golang.org/x/net@161cd47e91fd` (or just `go get golang.org/net` for `@latest`).